# iPad volume issues

Tags: ios, ipad, facetime, sound-volume

I seem to be having a strange problem with my iPad. The volume only sometimes works. The volume will be fully turned up and not muted, but it won't work. Then, without changing anything, a couple minutes later it will work. Or, I will try to FaceTime someone and I will not hear it ring on my end. Then when they answer, I can't hear them and they can't hear me. I'll try again a second after and it'll work again. It is never consistent though.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Is this just with the speakers?

Comment: did you check your headphone plug for contamination, something might be stuck in there

Answer (score 1):

maybe a setting has been changed, reset all settings and content or just all settings. after check the headphone plugs. as a last resort go to an apple store and tell them what is happening. 99% of the time they will fix it